# Recursively get files over FTP with explicit SSL

Tags: ftp, wget

Is there a way to recursively get a whole directory from another server using FTP with explicit SSL on Linux? I have tried a number of wget combinations including with and without the passive flag different SSLv/TLS flags etc and none seem to work. I get a "server refused the connection" message.

By contrast, I can pull up Transmit on my Mac and connect easily with the SSL option enabled.

Comment: I don't think wget supports ftps at all. Try curl.

Comment: curl support ftps and it doesn't need any -r or recursively option.

Comment: You might try using [`lftp`](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html)'s `mirror [source] [target]` command.  `lftp` supports FTPS as well.